# twitter bot on heroku error "No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, twitter, tweepy

I made a twitter bot in `python 3.5` using `tweepy` which updates status about the New followers everyday. The code runs smoothly on IDLE. I tried to deploy the bot on heroku but it keeps throwing error in the logs :

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

After going through similar questions, I tried the commands like :

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

but to no avail.
Here is my python program named `bot.py`

```
import tweepy
import sys
import time
import os
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = '' 
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
count=1
Past_Followers = 0
Current_Followers = 0
while(count>0):
   variable1 = api.get_user('USERNAME')
   Past_Followers = variable1.followers_count
   api.update_status(status='Follower count is '+str(Past_Followers))
   time.sleep(86400)
   variable2 = api.get_user('USERNAME')
   Current_Followers = variable2.followers_count
   api.update_status(status='Total Followers '+str(Current_Followers))
   api.update_status(status='New Followers Today = '+str(Current_Followers - Past_Followers))
   count=count+1
   print(count)
```

requirements.txt : `tweepy==3.5.0` ; runtime.txt : `python-3.5.2` and Procfile : `worker: python bot.py`

**Edit** : Worked using `heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to run your web process, when the bot is a worker. You want to `ps:scale worker=1` instead of `ps:scale web=1`. Web is for processes with `web:` in your Procfile and they have to be web apps.

Comment: Works like a charm :). Is there any setting by which we can do that before the deployment on Heroku?

Comment: Heroku should remember that your worker is running and whenever you deploy new version, it just resets it